# Display Wordpress Menu in OpenCart

Tags: php, wordpress, opencart

I would like to display a Wordpress Menu in the OpenCart Header.  In my test.php page I added the following code;

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-load.php');  
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Test' ) ); ?>
```

And it works great, however when I add that into the header.tpl template in OpenCart I receive an error;

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object() on a non-object in /....../wordpress/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 256
```

Can you assist? Have you done this before? Seems that OpenCart is causing the problem?

### **APPENDED UPDATE ON PROGRESS BELOW**

Okay, I have run default installations of OC and WP.

Wordpress is in the root - www.test.local
Opencart is in the root/store directory - www.test.local/store/

In the Opencart Default Tenplate Header I have the following code:

```
<?php $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php';
      echo $path;
      require_once($path);  
      wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Test' ) ); ?>
```

Which Generates the following error:

```
test.local/Sites/test.local/htdocs/wp-load.phpNotice: Constant DB_PASSWORD already defined in test.local/Sites/test.local/htdocs/wp-config.php on line 25Unknown: Redefining already defined constructor for class WP_Widget in test.local/Sites/test.local/htdocs/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 93Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in test.local/Sites/test.local/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3048
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object() on a non-object in test.local/Sites/test.local/htdocs/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 256
```

Interestingly though, when I delete the 'Test' Menu from Wordpress, the menu displays in Opencart, However I still see the following error:

```
/Sites/test.local/htdocs/wp-load.phpNotice: Constant DB_PASSWORD already defined in /Sites/test.local/htdocs/wp-config.php on line 25Unknown: Redefining already defined constructor for class WP_Widget in /Sites/test.local/htdocs/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 93Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Sites/test.local/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3048Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Sites/test.local/htdocs/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 845
```

A clue?  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why WP is throwing the error, but it's not OC that's causing the issue

Comment: Maybe posting that part of the `header.tpl` could help us understand what may be causing the problem...? Speaking of `header.tpl` - do You include that wordpress files directly into the template?

Comment: You need more than that to declare an object within WordPress and you need to define your root for WordPress. This is hideous code and it is a bad idea to chuck in raw PHP like that within the .tpl of OpenCart. Plugin and logical MVC is better. I made a post on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208488/how-to-make-a-simple-module-in-opencart-example-getting-latest-posts-from-wordp

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Very nice and extensive answer!

Comment: shadyyx - Don't think posting the header.tpl will help.  TheBlackBenzKid, that is helpful, but it pulls the posts, I'm not to sure on amending for the menus. Jay - You are the man, always there and answering, but this time.... your hands tired?

Comment: TheBlackBenzKid, that is helpful, but it pulls the posts, I'm not to sure on amending for the menus, I have just tested this in the header files (tpl/php), but get an error from one of the vqmods (Parse error: parse error in /......./vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_common_header.php on line 167).

Answer (score 1):

i believe you would need to include the wp-blog-header.php not the wp-load take a look at this
http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/use-wordpress-as-a-php-framework-for-your-static-html-pages/

Comment: Thanks for this. This is a pretty good post and article. It would be better to insert the article inside here with all the tags and actually do the mod and practice yourself and I am sure an answer is worth it. Good link +1

Comment: @Stuart have you define the menu in the functions.php file? have you installed wordpress prior to excute any code?

Comment: The WP and OC installations work fine.  store. for the OC installation and www. for the WP install, could that be the issue?  How should I manually specify the menu in the WP functions file, it works in WP and in the store. site as a test.php file.  I borks when it is put into one of the OC pages.

Comment: you will need to register your menu on the functions.php file like this register_nav_menu('Test', 'Menu Label goes here'); also if you added the include('wp-blog-header.php') to your test.php you should be able to call bloginfo('title') and you should be able to see the your wordpress title so make sure that you can call other wordpress  function

Comment: Still the same error Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object() on a non-object in /...../wordpress/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 256

Comment: $wp_query = $GLOBALS['wp_query']; add this to your functions.php it would help if you can show some of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The "Constant DB_PASSWORD already defined" is thrown because WP and OC use the same define variable for database password. You need to change the OC DB_PASSWORD variable name to DB_PASSWORD_OC, and then in index.php change the following:

// Database

$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
...

to comply with the new variable name:

// Database

$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD_OC, DB_DATABASE);