# OpenCart - Need to Create New Section Same as "Manifacturers"

Tags: php, opencart

I need to create a new section as same as manifacturers. only its name should be "authors".

I tried to make it. I changed databases, I changed files and created new files as like as "manifacturers". But It couldn't work than I got it: I can't make it without any help.

What should I do? Which document should I read to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do little bit of research bro..
you can go this link

http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/9781783280377_Chapter-01.pdf

or

[How to make a simple module in OpenCart? Example getting latest posts from Wordpress and showing it in OpenCart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208488/how-to-make-a-simple-module-in-opencart-example-getting-latest-posts-from-wordp)