# How to create Opencart Module for to different users?

Tags: javascript, php, html, module, opencart

I am new in OpenCart CMS. I know how to create a simple module for OpenCart.But i have some confusion here.

1. Difference between Admin and Catalog?
2. I can create user in the admin panel with module.But how to create 2 kind of users who can register/login in the front-end and can sell the item of the OpenCart Store.
3. How can i configure it so that user can sell any item in front-end? How to fetch data for this?

I want to create 2 kinds of user .One kind user who can 1.able to register and upload his item and able to sell item (named as supplier) and other user 2. just able to sell item (Normal User).so how can i give this authority ?

I have searched and found this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208488/how-to-make-a-simple-module-in-opencart-example-getting-latest-posts-from-wordp).Please have anyone who can put an end of my confusion about this?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: you will need a lot more than a module to achieve that. A merchant must have access to the Admin area to add items. The login in the front end is for customers to BUY products, and reviews their personal info and previous orders etc etc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) - Difference between Admin and Catalog?**

Admin is where you and the staff/partners login to manage the online store. Add categories, products, customers, orders (if you want to take order by phone for example). in short anything that has to do with store management.
The Catalog is the facade of your store, it is what a visitor to your site will see.

**2)I can create user in the admin panel with module.But how to create 2 kind of users who can register/login in the front-end and can sell the item of the OpenCart Store.**
I am not sure what you mean by module here. There are two type of users, an Admin user / and a Customer.
Admins are anyone who has access to the backend of your store and can performs tasks according to the level of privileges you grant them. if you want someone to be able to post product you must give him/her access to you admin, in other words, you must create an admin user.
A customer is just that, anyone visiting your site is a customer.

**3) How can i configure it so that user can sell any item in front-end? How to fetch data for this?**
For this you will need some major work. you will have to create the front end view for submission, with the controller and model that goes with it.

That said, you must consider how a user will be collecting the payment, open cart only allows for 1 payment gateway setting. So if you added your paypal account, that will be only account. But then again, you could work it out, but you will end up making a LOT of changes.

Opencart is easy to modify, the code is straight forward, although subject to debate on its quality, but it's opensource, you could build on it, or fork from it and create your own.

Cheers

Comment: I think he is discussing about `seller concept` in online store

Comment: @zedBlackbeard a seller must access the backend, there is no such thing as front end seller in opencart

Comment: I want to create 2 kinds of user .One kind user who can 1.able to register and upload his item and able to sell item (named as supplier) and other user 2. just able to sell item.so how can i give this authority ?

Comment: @user1709251 : As i know, seller has his own seller setting section to manage products and order under my account section.

Comment: @zedBlackbeard you would need to extend opencart to do that. it is not out of the box

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud check out the opencart extensions site. there are extensions that will help you achieve that.

Comment: @user1709251 can refer me any extension name which is good.Free extension is better for me.Thank you very much for clearing me. :D